How to get the static reflect.Type of an interface?
This panics since the type is already nil:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "reflect"
)

var w io.Writer

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(w)) // .String()
}

I would like to get io.Writer as output: https://play.golang.com/p/WOdN54nWW-I
How to get the reflect.Type of an interface? and Better way to get the reflect.Type of an interface in Go don't work since they require to know the type up-front.

Sorry, seems that casting nil to error got me side-tracked.

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "reflect"
)

var w io.Writer

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&w).Elem()) // .String()
}

https://play.golang.com/p/aUO5o_B0CsB
